# Python Path Library Using regular expressions to search for files

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, path

I am trying to remove duplicate files(rather the files with extended "(number)" in the end. 
I am using regular expression `"^[a-zA-z0-9_]+\([0-9]*\)\.pdf$"` for that purpose. There is no issue with the regex.

Following is my code

```
import re;
from path import path;
pattern1 = re.compile("^[a-zA-z0-9_]+\([0-9]*\)\.pdf$");
p = path("/home/jill/Downloads/Dinamalar (copy)")   
#Deletes the duplicates in the folder    
for f in p.files(pattern = pattern1):
    print f
```

But I am getting

> TypeError: "object of type '_sre.SRE_Pattern' has no len()"

in the for loop. what seems to be missing?

Are there any better approaches to do this?

Comment: What path module are you using?

Comment: This one. Apparently this is a wrapper on os.path 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py

Comment: Try passing in a raw pattern string and not a compiled pattern as `p.files` pattern keyword argument.

Comment: Yep. worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not compile the regular expression.  Instead, just pass the string directly to `p.files`:

```
for f in p.files(pattern="^[a-zA-z0-9_]+\([0-9]*\)\.pdf$"):
    print f
```

(This answer based on a comment by @Shashank)